# Rails command Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im about to start work on another web application, I change directories to

> /rails_projects

and enter

> rails new blank

I then get this error

```
Error: Command not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The common rails commands available for engines are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 destroy     Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")

All commands can be run with -h for more information.

If you want to run any commands that need to be run in context
of the application, like `rails server` or `rails console`,
you should do it from application's directory (typically test/dummy).
```

I have reinstalled rails, and still same error, any ideas?

UPDATE:

It actually give me the same error when I type just

> rails -h
>
> rails

in cmd

Comment: what version is your rails? Have to tries rails -v? Also, do you have ruby install?

Comment: rails version 4.0.2 Ruby version 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into this error and needs a last resort plan.

I ended up uninstalling rails, rvm, and installing a newer version of ruby and new gemset.

```
rvm implode
gem uninstall rails -v=4.0.2
gem uninstall railities
```

install rvm :

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
rvm get stable
```

for mac:

```
brew install libtool libxslt libksba openssl
brew install libyaml
```

install ruby:

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

if you have error

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/opt/openssl
```

install new ruby gems from website.  Unpackage it then go to folder and run

```
ruby setup.rb
gem update --system 2.1.9
```

install rails (you can choose your version)

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.2
gem install railties
```

I did this, and now system is working normal again.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone with a similar error that may land here, this fixed it for me:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

This will generate "new" versions of the binaries. Just say `Yes` when it inquires you to replace them.

Comment: I think this is `rails app:update:bin` now....

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to upgrade a Rails Engine from 3.2 to 4.1.

The culprit was the presence of `script/rails` which contained:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

ENGINE_ROOT = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../../lib/my_project/engine', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'rails/engine/commands'
```

The problem line is there at the end: `require 'rails/engine/commands`. That was not allowing the full Rails CLI to load which omitted the `new` command. Removing that file solved my problem.

I'm pretty sure this wasn't the cause of your specific problem, but the symptoms were the same as mine and this was the first link in Google for the error message. Just passing along my findings to help anyone else that runs into this same situation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rails command believes it's inside of a rails engine, which is why a different set of commands are available to you. Notice the 'commands available for engines' text. New is not a command available for engines. I'm not sure why rails thinks the directory you're in is an engine, but likely your directory structure is mixed up somehow.

Comment: I made a new dir, and tried the command inside of that directory, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Create another directory and run `$ruby -v`, check which version is available. Now run `rails new app_name`. Try once after closing the terminal and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me when a require error occurred in a gem (dependency) while loading.